# WebGL glow effect

Tags: glsl, webgl, shader, fragment-shader

I started learning shaders, playing around on ShaderToy.com. For a project I want to make, I need to create an arbitrary glow filter on WebGL (not Bloom). I want to calculate alpha that I can then use to draw a color glow or use for some animated texture like fire etc.

So far I thought of a few ideas:

1. Averaging alpha across some area near each pixel - obviously slow
2. Going in circle around each pixel in one loop then over distance in another to calculate alpha based on how close the shape is to this pixel - probably just as slow
3. Blur entire shape - sounds like an overkill since I just need the alpha

Are there other ideas for approaching this? All I can find are gaussian blur techniques from bloom-like filters.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What is (are) your input(s), what is your output ? You want to calculate an alpha from what ? And what do you want at the end ? A blurred alpha texture ? The average alpha value for an image ? Something else ? Please clarify your question

Comment: @Zouch, I want to create a glow around arbitrary object that I could customize (color, distance, intensity, etc). After spending a whole day googling and reading some articles I figured I will try this approach:
http://xissburg.com/faster-gaussian-blur-in-glsl/
Will probably answer my own question with a Codepen once I have time to make it but thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please find this nvidia [document](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/10/opengl/src/simple_glow/doc/simple_glow.pdf) for the simple glow effect.
The basic idea is to

1. render the scene in the back buffer
2. activate the effect
3. render some elements of the scene in a FBO
4. compute the Glow effect
5. bind the final FBO as a texture and blend this effect with the previously rendered scene in the backbuffer