# Glow effect on simple rectangle in openGL ES

Tags: glsl, webgl, opengl-es-2.0

I would like to create a glow effect, on a rectangle:

I don't really know where to start the fragment shader.

[image: ..]

Actually, I would like to achieve this effect on shapes (circles, polygons, rectangles). There is no real border color. There are just blury.

Comment: Check my answer in a similar post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36263404/webgl-glow-effect/36290626#36290626

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways:

If you have a rectangle defined with 4 lines (4 points) and have a model matrix then multiply the 4 points with the model matrix and send them as a uniform into the fragment shader. In vertex shader create another varying for the position which is the input position multiplied with the model matrix only. Also some radius must be sent as a uniform.

Now in the fragment shader create code for each of the point pairs representing a line and compute a distance. Now if the distance is smaller then radius create a color scale for the border. The sum of all 4 is then used as a result for the border color.

```
scale += 1.0-(clamp(currentDistanceToLeftBorder/radius, .0, 1.0));
scale += 1.0-(clamp(currentDistanceToTopBorder/radius, .0, 1.0));
scale += 1.0-(clamp(currentDistanceToRightBorder/radius, .0, 1.0));
scale += 1.0-(clamp(currentDistanceToBottomBorder/radius, .0, 1.0));
```

Then mix the colors:

```
color = mix(defaultColor, borderColor, clamp(scale, .0, 1.0));
```